# commands do not get executed using at (bash terminal)

Tags: linux, bash, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to backup a directory on a scheduled time using at

That's an example i tried:

```
tar -cvf ~/backup.tar ~/Music | at 13:00
```

but this immediately creates the backup without waiting for 13:00

I thought of using

```
at 13:00 << EOF 
tar -cvf ~/backup.tar ~/Music 
EOF
```

but this never executed the command

what can I do to run the command on a scheduled time?(i must only use "at")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tar ... |` runs tar. Learn how pipes work.

`at` reads the commands from standard input. You can use a pipe to send a command to it, but you have to feed the command to the pipe, not its output:

```
echo tar -cvf ~/backup.tar ~/Music | at 13:00
```